# Displaying surface with non-rectangular boundary

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, 3d, surface

Refer to the attached image. I want to display the image in Matlab using the function `surf()`. However, I only want to display the region of the actual object without the background (the pale-green region surrounding the actual object which has 0 value). How to do that? I tried replacing all the outer region with `0` with `NaN` and setting all the values in the height map to a nonzero value, but still I get an error message:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

So how can I display a surface that has a non-rectangular boundary?

[image]

Comment: just figured out the problem. I haven't clear all previously stored variables. Now is ok thanks for the ans btw

Comment: Glad it worked. If it was a matter of clearing previous variables, it seems my contribution has been marginal, though :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting those values to `NaN` should do. Here's an example:

```
[x, y] = ndgrid(linspace(-1,1,500));
z = cos(2*pi*(x+y)*2);
z(x.^2+y.^2>1) = NaN; %// remove values outside unit circle
surf(x,y,z,'edgecolor','none')
colorbar
view(2)
axis equal
```

[image]